# How to use Facebook authentication return "session" parameter?

Tags: c#, facebook

After successful authentication, Facebook redirects me to the canvas callback url with the parameter *installed* and *session*. the session parameter is like this...

```
    &session=
{%22session_key%22%3A%222.cQWUqNcffzsWReDAcctOmA__.3600.1281524400-100000327994753%22%2C%22uid%22%3A100000327994753%2C%22expires%22%3A1281524400%2C%22secret%22%3A%22xOodxtnGGNMIK0F4Zq_sCw__%22%2C%22sig%22%3A%223eb5b89dd11e3b42d46587921ebecc52%22}
```

after decode it looks like

```
&session={
    "session_key":"2.cQWUqNcffzsWReDAcctOmA__.3600.1281524400-111111327994753",
    "uid":111111327994753,"
    expires":1281524400,
    "secret":"xOodxtnGGNMIK0F4Zq_sCw__","
    sig":"3eb5b89dd11e3b42d46587921ebecc52"}
```

**Now the prblem is that I have no idea that how i use this parameter in C# SDK. I want to get permission and also want to get auth_toke**.

In FB's documentation, "accesstoken" and "auth_token" are used. Are they the same or different?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guy, but the session parameter is just [JSON](http://json.org/) - and there appears to be a plethora of ways to parse JSON in C#.

In regards to the phrases "access token" vs "auth_token" - could you provide links to two FB documentation pages that use each term?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Facebook .Net SDK on Codeplex http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com. It will handle all the 'dirty work' for you. For example, I could call the following code either from a controller action or on Page_Load.

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
string accessToken = app.Session.AccessToken;
long userId = app.UserId;
```

Thats it. You don't really need to worry about how facebook is returning the data to you. The SDK handles all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

String Session_Key=Request.QueryString.Get("session_key");

long User_Id=long.Parse(Request.QueryString.Get("uid").ToString());